# type error in ocaml - This expression has type (string * 'a) list, but is used with type exp

Tags: types, ocaml

I, i have this simple program in ocaml

```
type tree = Node of string * exp * tree * tree | Empty 

and exp = Etree of tree |  EInt of int  | List of (string*exp);;

let rec evalNode.......



and rec eval (e:exp) =
(match e with
     | EInt _ -> e
     | Etree(tree) -> (match tree with 
         | Empty -> [] 
         | Node(s,i,t1,t2) -> (evalNode (tree)) )

  )
```

evalNode : tree -> (string * exp) list = fun

eval : exp -> exp = fun

but return this error but i don't undestand what does means, there aren't much information of ocaml in the web:

This expression has type (string * 'a) list,
but is used with type exp.

Etree has a type Node inside, so is type tree, so i can call evalNode with this value because it want a tree type

evalNode return a list of (string*exp) but is a exp so eval can return this

Comment: I think you might confuse `List of (string*exp)` for `(string*exp) list`

Comment: I believe @glennsl nailed it, but without the location of the error source, without the actual code, we can only guess your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Any expression in Ocaml has to return a single type.  So, for example, you can't write something like `if a>b then "a" else 7` because it doesn't know whether the type of that expression is string or int.

In your eval function, without meaning to, you're doing something similar.  When `e` is an `EInt` the first matching option is triggered and it returns `e` which has type `exp`.  When `e` is an `Etree(Empty)` it triggers the second matching option which in turn calls the second match statement and the first matching option within that is triggered, returning `[]`, which is a list having type `'a list` (meaning list of unknown type).  When `e` is an `Etree(Node(s,i,t1,t2))` the second matching option in the second match statement is triggered, returning `evalnode(tree)` which we know from what you've written to have type `(string * exp) list`.

So, the inner match, by itself is fine since it can unify a generic list with a specific list.  But combining the outer match is problematic since the first case returns an `exp` and the second case returns a `(string * exp) list` so it doesn't know what type the expression should have.  I'm not sure why the error says `(string * 'a) list` rather than `(string * exp) list` but I suspect you can fix things without having to work that out.

I do also want to note that you have a constructor `List of (string*exp)` whose subtype is not a list.  You may wish this to be `List of (string*exp) list` and then to have your inner match return `List([])` and `List(evalNode(tree))` but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

> evalNode return a list of (string*exp) but is a exp

This is your error: a list of `string * exp` is not an `exp`; the compiler cannot guess that you meant to apply the constructor `List` to build an `exp` from this list (if the right definition of `List` happens to be `List of (string * exp) list`).